# Define methods of anonymous class in another file

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, anonymous-class

I have the following base class:

```
class Network::ActivationFunction
{
public:
    virtual double evaluate(double x) =0
    virtual double evaluate_derivative(double x) =0
};
```

This is meant to be a base class for activation functions for neurons in a neural network. I want to have different objects with different types of sigmoids/relu/...

I don't really want to have multiple instances of any particular activation function, so I would like to do something like this:

```
class : public Network::ActivationFunction
{
public:
    double evaluate(double x);
    double evaluate_derivative(double x);
} logisticActivationFunction;
```

And then have the functions defined in a .cpp file. However, since it is anonymous I don't know how I can define it's member functions in another file.

So how can I either make the above idea work, or in any other way have only one instance of the specific activation function?

Comment: Unfortuntely C++ simply doesn't work this way. The closest to something like this is declaring a class in an anonymous namespace within a single translation unit, which means that everything, including everything that uses the anonymous class, is contained inside a single .cpp file.

Comment: I mean I can just have the function definition in the header file and then it works. So C++ does work. I am just asking if there is another way without braking the interface/implementation barrier.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how I can define it's member functions in another file.

That's because you can't. It is not possible to define member functions of an unnamed<sup>†</sup> class outside the class definition, so it is not possible to define them in another file.

<sup>†</sup> A bit of technical pedantry: The class is not anonymous; it is unnamed.

> What is the difference?

Unnamed classes are simply classes with no name like your example class. Anonymous class is a member of another class, where neither the class nor the member object have a name. Example:

```
struct foo {
    union { // no class name
        int i;
        char c;
    };      // no name for the member object
}:
```

Only unions can be anonymous in C++. Anonymous non-union classes are ill-formed. <sub>Anonymous structs are allowed in C (since C11); this is a case where the languages are incompatible.</sub>

> or in any other way have only one instance of the specific activation function?

Well, as long as you instantiate only once, then there will only ever be one instance. If it is important for correctness of the program to have only one instance, then you can enforce that using the singleton pattern.

Singleton can be implemented by making all constructors private, making the class non-copyable (and non-movable) and writing a static member factory function that returns a reference to a local static instance:

```
class LogisticActivationFunction : public Network::ActivationFunction
{
    public:
        static LogisticActivationFunction& get()
        {
            static LogisticActivationFunction obj;
            return obj;
        }

        double evaluate(double x);
        double evaluate_derivative(double x);

        // prevent copying / moving
        LogisticActivationFunction(LogisticActivationFunction const&) = delete;

     private:
         // allow only member functins to construct
         LogisticActivationFunction() = default;
};
```

> what about the solution of just having the definitions in the header file?

Just making the class unnamed doesn't prevent user of the class from making copies of the one instance, thereby creating more, so it doesn't technically enforce your requirement to have only one instance.

Declaring copy constructor of an unnamed class is not possible, so you cannot declare them deleted or private. A trick to prevent copying could be to add a non-copyable, non-movable member object. But I would recommend the singleton pattern described above instead.

Comment: What is the difference? And do you have any other propositions how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: Also, what about the solution of just having the definitions in the header file?

Comment: @indjev99 To be honest it's not clear what the problem is. If you don't want more than one instance, don't make more than one instance. Are you facing some issue where more instances are being created than you would like, and which is forcing you to fix it by preventing more than one instance, rather than by removing the unwanted instance creations? Please explain in detail.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well the code I am writing is supposed to be used as a sort of library (even if it is not actually going to be used) and I don't want it to be able to be misused.

Comment: Usually in C++ we don't go too far down that path. Just document how the library is supposed to be used, and if people use it wrong, that's their own problem! Otherwise you make your design unnecessarily complex and hard-to-maintain and not for much gain.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. I've just been programming in some other languages recently that do this sort of thing and I sort of got used to it.